# Create table in appendix

Tags: tables, appendices, appendix

I am drafting an article in LaTeX, but having troubles to move tables from the text to the Appendix. I am using \appendix command, and then using standard code for creating a table. However, the table does not appear in the Appendix, rather it shows up in the main text. Please help.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{appendix}
\begin{document}
\section{Introduction}
\subsection{Literature}
\appendix

\section{Appendix: Additional Figures}
\begin{table}[]
    \centering
    \begin{tabular}{c|c}
         &  \\
         & 
    \end{tabular}
    \caption{Caption}
    \label{tab:my_label}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`\begin{table}[]` means "do not allow the table anywhere". That generates  a warning and the argument is changed:

```
LaTeX Warning: No positions in optional float specifier.
               Default added (so using `tbp') on input line 9.
```

But you do not want a top float here so use `[hbp]`

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{appendix}
\begin{document}
\section{Introduction}
\subsection{Literature}
\appendix

\section{Appendix: Additional Figures}
\begin{table}[hbp]
    \centering
    \begin{tabular}{c|c}
         &  \\
         & 
    \end{tabular}
    \caption{Caption}
    \label{tab:my_label}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: This works, thanks a lot. What stands for [hbt]?

Comment: @Sane allows the float `here, bottom of page or top of page` (or as I had it, with `p` on a page of floats)

Comment: I see, thank you.

Comment: When I use [hbt], all of sudden the reference list which should come after the table in Appendix splits into two parts -- one before the table, another part after the table. Should I use another argument instead of [hbt] to guarantee that bibliography appears right after table in Appendix?

Comment: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/2275/keeping-tables-figures-close-to-where-they-are-mentioned

Comment: Great, thanks a lot!